# How to attach a PDF document that takes a string format

Tags: c#, pdf, sendmail

I Build a PDF Document from a URL where customers go to redeem a MSC Cruises voucher. I have tested and it builds the PDF, displays it to the user, and also saves it in a folder directory.

```
DataTable dt = verifyRedemption(VoucherRemption);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string strVCode = dt.Rows[0]["voucherCode"].ToString();

            // save pdf document
            string fileLoc = ""; 
            fileLoc += context.Server.MapPath("PDFs");
            fileLoc += "/";
            fileLoc += strVCode + ".pdf";

            doc.Save(fileLoc);

            // close pdf document
            doc.Close();

            MailHelper SendPdf = new MailHelper();
            SendPdf.SendEmail("MSC Cruises", "Kei@3tier.co.za", "Your voucher email", "Hi, <br/><br/> Please see your voucher ", doc.Pages.ToString());

            context.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
```

Except when im sending emails, i have to send 5 string formats, is there a way to change how i send this as a pdf attachment? (Doc was declared before the datatable, when i build the PDF.

Comment: What's `MailHelper`?

Comment: Its the class i use to send emails, i have tried specifying that its an attachment, but it says it cant convert it into a Document.

Comment: "send a string format", what does this mean?

Comment: Please use MailMessage

[Refer here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the System.Net.Mail Namespace?

It provides the following:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("MailFrom", "MailTo");
//Then you could do sth to grab your files like before:
List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
foreach(string attachmentPath in docs)
{
    //Here you provide the path where you saved the pdf
    attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentPath));
}
mail.Subject = "Here comes the PDF";
mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
mail.Body = "Your message here";

SmtpClient mailer = new SmtpClient();
mailer.EnableSsl = true; //Depends on your mailserver if he forces to use SSL

//(Same procedure as setting up a new Outlook Account...)
mailer.Host = "mail.gmx.net"; //for example:
mailer.Port = "587"; //Default SMTP-Port is 25

mailer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
//Just your common LoginData for this server
mailer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("EmailUserName", "EmailPassword");

mailer.Send(mail);
```

All you need to do is to "find" the pdf's you saved to some directory before, to get the Path of it and create an attachment from it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @FeDe, How would i find the information for these parts specified below

Comment: SmtpClient mailer = new SmtpClient();
mailer.EnableSsl = true;
mailer.Host = "Your mailserver";
mailer.Port = "Your mailservers port;
mailer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
mailer.Credentials = "Your credentials";